# Drag IMPORTRANGE formula and auto fill multiple cells

Tags: google-sheets, importrange

I import multiple cells by a checkbox with this formula:

```
=IF(A1=True;ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("URL";"Sheet1!A1:A10"));"")
```

But I'm looking for a solution to be able to drag the cells so they auto fill like this:

```
=IF(A1=True;ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("URL";"Sheet1!A1:A10"));"")
=IF(B1=True;ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("URL";"Sheet1!B1:B10"));"")
=IF(C1=True;ARRAYFORMULA(IMPORTRANGE("URL";"Sheet1!C1:C10"));"")
```

I found this solution but can't make it work with multiple cells:

```
=IMPORTRANGE("<URL>","Sheet!"&ADDRESS(ROW(A21),Column(Q1)))
```

I know that import range slows down google sheets, but I have maybe 10 documents with personal information and have to retrieve the information this way.

Thanks on behalf.

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour). Consider sharing a publicly editable [sample spreadsheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/269219) with realistic-looking data and an example of what your expected results should look like.

Answer (score 0):

Use one `importrange()` call to bring in all the data, and conditionally show the values in a column, or a blank, like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  if( 
    A1:C1; 
    importrange("id"; "Sheet1!A1:C10"); 
    iferror(1/0) 
  ) 
)
```